# arithmetic operations on list elements in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, expression

I got this task in Prolog and I don't know how to approach it.

I have to write predicate `expression(List,Outcome,Result)` which builds an arithmetic expression using every element from `List`. It gives a `Result` which must be equal to `Outcome` before backtracking.

For example:

```
?- expression([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, X).
X = 1+ (2+ (3-4))
```

or

```
?- expression([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, X).
X = 1+ ((2-3)*4+5)
```

I've tried something like this:

```
operation(A, B, A + B).
operation(A, B, A - B).
operation(A, B, A * B).
operation(A, B, A div B).

expression([],_,_).
expression([A,B,D|List],Outcome,Result) :-
    operation(A,B,C),
    operation(C,D,Result),
    Outcome is Result.
```

And this works for list of three elements, but I want to use it for different sizes of list. I assume I have to use recursion, but how? And how to add the possibility of using parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Each expression is a tree. Its leaves' *fringe* is always the same list - the given 1st argument. Its structure reflects parenthesization. Then for each tree its nodes - when "viewed from above" - form a list of arithmetic binary operators. For each tree you need to consider all combinations of these operators.

```erlang
expression( List, Result, Xpr ) :-
   tree( List, T, Nodes ),              % N elts in List, N-1 in Nodes
   combinations( Nodes, [+,-,*,/] ),    % or whatever ops you want to use
   evaluate( T, Result ),
   parenthesized( T, Xpr ).

combinations( Nodes, Ops ) :-           % use_module( library( lambda )).
   maplist( \X^(member(X, Ops)), Nodes ).
```

All that's left is to implement what's left to implement.